# Anaconda: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, pyside

I'm having trouble with Anaconda Navigator. The program isn't lauching anymore, I think it happened after I shutdown my Windows 11 and forced the program to close. When I try to launch it in the Anaconda Prompt, I have the following lines of errors:

```
(base) C:\Users\user>anaconda-navigator

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 209, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 119, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 19, in <module>
    from qtpy import PYQT5
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 215, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

I've tried solutions in Stackoverflow and already reinstalled the program, but nothing worked yet. If anyone can help, I will appreciate very much!

EDIT: The program returned to normal alone, don't know what happened.

Comment: `already reinstalled the program` <- what have you reinstalled and how?

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled the last version of Anaconda Navigator. I also can run Jupyer Lab, that I was using before this bug, with the Anaconda Prompt, but Anaconda Navigator still not launching.